# How to make Internet Explorer to treat .eml files like .mht?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer is capable to open MIME files with `.mht` extension. How to make IE to render `.eml` files as well?

Steps I have tried:

1. Open With Internet Explorer: IE render `.eml` as plain text (not readable especially when base64 encoding is used)
2. Changing registry `HKCR/.eml@(Default)` to `mhtmlfile`: IE shows download prompt
3. Setting registry `HKCR/.eml@Content Type` to `message/rfc822`: IE shows `The address is not valid`

Reasons: I do not want to download any extra software for that, as IE can render MIME. I do not want to rename the `.eml` file to `.mht` before opening.

Comment: Apparently renaming the files to .mht (as in your question) should work... or do you *not* want to have to do this (your question is unclear)?

Comment: @BigChris I want to tweak IE to treat `.eml` files as `.mht`. (I've fixed the question.)

Comment: I have the same idea, it is a pain to deploy and install on our LAN clients another software only for this purpose.

Comment: did you try with mimetypes multipart/related or multipart/mixed instead of message/rfc822  ?